# font family size different size between in ie 11 and chrome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

im using this code

```
.mainmenu {
  font-family: signpainter;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 21px;
  letter-spacing: 0.7px;
  display: table;
  text-align: left;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

but font looks different in IE (it's smaller) than it is in Firefox and Chrome.

this my code embed font-family

```
@font-face{
font-family: signpainter;
src: url('fonts/SignPainter.otf'),
     url('fonts/signpainter.eot'),
     url('fonts/signpainter.woff'),
     url('fonts/signpainter.ttf');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Does anyone know why? And how do I fix it in IE-11?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's well known that browsers render elements in a different way, so I would say it's normal, I think you should try [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), this may help you

Comment: Thanks for reply,
i has try with normalize.css , but it does not work to me..